# Where does xdg-mime save its per-user default app settings?

Tags: configuration, mime-types, xdg-open

Where does xdg-mime save the settings I make with commands which set the default app to handle MIME types? i.e. commands such as:

```
xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

?

I'm using SLES (SUSE Linux Enterprise) 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at some other questions on unix.SE, I was expecting that to be at:

```
$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

but actually, it turns out that at least on my system, it's at:

```
$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list
```

And it will look like this:

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=evince.desktop
```

(plus any other settings you've made.)